# How do I calculate a desirable sample size for a given power when I have a small sample of data to start with?

Tags: anova, statistical-power

I have 5 data points each from Group A and Group B

```
df <- data.frame(
    duration=c(
       17.133,14.400,12.083,16.767,17.550, 
       13.867,14.567,15.467,14.300,16.667
    ),
    group=rep(c('A','B'), each=5)
)
```

`duration` is in seconds.

A brief summary is as follows:

```
> df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(mean=mean(duration), sd=sd(duration))

  group       mean    sd
  <fctr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 A           15.6  2.31
2 B           15.0  1.11

...

> summary(lm(duration ~ group, data=df))

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        14.9736     0.7823  19.140 2.33e-10 ***
groupB              0.6130     1.1063   0.554    0.590
```

In an ANOVA model, there is no significant difference between these two groups. I would like to determine what sample size I would likely need in order to achieve a power of 90% with a significance level of 5%.

And, although effect size is usually given in standardized units, would it be reasonable to translate it to the units of the dependent variable (e.g., 0.5 seconds), or is it best to make a rough inference of what the effect size would be based on the data given?

edit: I am aware that this crosses into the territory of *p*-hacking, although I think that there is an acceptable trade-off between marginally reducing the integrity of results (for which the sample size of 5 is almost certainly too low anyway) and accurately determining a good number of samples to take.

The context of this is a chaotic computer simulation which cannot be analytically solved.

Comment: $\mu_1 = 15.6, \mu_2 = 15.0, \sigma = 2.3, \alpha = 0.05$ and power = 0.90, two-sided test ==> sample size = 309 for each group. Total sample size = 618.  https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~rollin/stats/ssize/n2.html

Comment: There is uncertainty in the mu and sigma of the normal distributions, though.

Comment: Use your best guess on them (mu, sigma,...) if you have more information apart from these small samples. If there is no uncertainty, no statistics.

Comment: @user158565 You can take account of the uncertainty in the parameters; you are not necessarily stuck with the (on average lower) power that would result from a 'best guess'